# upload_max_filesize is set to 64 MB already but WordPress is still showing 2 MB

Tags: uploads, media, media-library

I have configured the `upload_max_filesize` directive to **64 MB** in my localhost `php.ini` and have my Apache restarted.

But why the Media section in my WordPress still showing 2 MB below?

```
Maximum upload file size: 2 MB.
```

So any file is more than 2 MB, I get this error below:

> The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

Any ideas what else I have to configure?

**EDIT 1:**

I also have set `post_max_size = 64M` to match `upload_max_filesize = 64M` in `php.ini` and have my Apache restarted.

**EDIT 2:**

Found the problem. I am running on a **PHP Development Server**. And probably because of this, WordPress cannot read my `php.ini`. It is fine on my production server.

So that's no why to increase the `upload_max_filesize` on a PHP Development Server then?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `post_max_size = 64M` to match `upload_max_filesize = 64M` in php.ini

Comment: done that already too

Answer (score 1):

There's a filter that may be set: [`upload_size_limit`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upload_size_limit/). Check to see if this filter's being used in a plugin or your active theme.

It's also possible, if you've got a lot of files uploaded, that you're running out of disk space (or, if this is a site in a Multisite network, you may be getting close to the site's quota).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have found out what the problem is.

Comment: see my edit 2. thanks